# DigitalPersona U.are.U 4500 Fingerprint Reader SDK not working with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fingerprint, filemaker, biometrics, digital-persona-sdk

I'm currently working to integrate the DigitalPersona U.are.U 4500 Fingerprint Reader with our FileMaker application. I installed the DigitalPersona SDK 1.6.1 on my system (Windows 10 Pro x64, 1904 Build 18362). However, the SDK samples do not seem to work while launching the scanner window. It gives the error: "ERROR: The RPC Server is not listening (0x800706B3)". I checked the 'Remote Procedure Call' and 'DCOM Server Process Launcher' but they're already running.

I then installed the SDK on an older Windows 10 installation (64 bit, 1709 Build 16299). The sample applications ran, but when the scanner window launches, it does not detect the connected fingerprint reader. I tried switching the device driver from "U.are.U 4500 Fingerprint Reader (WBF)" to the normal "U.are.U 4500 Fingerprint Reader" but it didn't help.

I tried the Biometric Fingerprint Plugin (by Productive Computing) for FileMaker and installed version 2.0.1.2. It comes with a sample FileMaker application for enrolling fingerprints and searching them. The plugin installed correctly, however, it also gives me the same issue upon scanner Window launch. The error message says "The fingerprint reader is not connected. Connect the reader." A screenshot is shown below.

[DigitalPersona U.are.U 4500 Fingerprint reader not detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBX1a.png)

As a result, I am neither able to use the code samples given with the SDK, nor able to use the demo file provided by the plugin, because the plugin isn't getting detected. I thought maybe the device was faulty, but it is working fine with Windows Hello fingerprint sign-in (using the WBF driver), as well as with the TimeDrop software (using the simple, non-WBF driver). The SDK is working with neither of these drivers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this SDK compatible with Windows 10? I have used it with Windows 7 some 8 years ago but haven't tried it with Windows 10. I'm not sure how dependable/accurate this website is however it says Windows 7 as the latest version.  https://digitalpersona-one-touch-for-windows-sdk.software.informer.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

Go to the **Device Manager** and locate the fingerprint device. Then **Right Click >> Update Driver >> Browse my computer for drivers >> Let me pick from a list of available drivers**.

Select a driver that does not have the term "WBF" in it. Windows Biometric Framework (WBF) drivers seem to be incompatible with the SDK.

Also, SDK version 2.2.3 works with Windows 10. Older SDKs are incompatible.

Comment: Good answer Crack